# как использовать non-static метод в non-static методе

Tags: java, методы

использовать метод sumOfSalaryInTheDepartment в методе averageSalary. проблема в строке double sumOfSalaryInTheDepartment = EmployeeBook.sumOfSalaryInTheDepartment(department); не могу обратиться через EmloyeeBook, т.к метод non-static и не понимаю как создать обьект для использования метода

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int max = 2;
        EmployeeBook arr = new EmployeeBook(max);
        arr.insert("Ivan", 3, 45999);
        arr.insert("Valya", 3, 56667);

        double sum = arr.sumOfSalaryInTheDepartment(3);
        System.out.println("Sum of salaries in department 3: " + sum);

//        double average = arr.averageSalary(3);
//        System.out.println("Average salary in department 3: " + average);
    }
}
class Employee {
    private String name;
    private int department;
    private double salary;
    final private int id;
    private static int nextId = 1;

    public Employee(String name, int department, double salary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.department = department;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.id = nextId;
        nextId++;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setDepartment(int department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

}
class EmployeeBook {
    private final Employee[] employees;
    private int countOfElements;

    public EmployeeBook(int max) {
        employees = new Employee[max];
        countOfElements = 0;
    }


    public void insert(String name, int department, double salary) {
        employees[countOfElements] = new Employee(name, department, salary);
        countOfElements++;
    }

    public double sumOfSalaryInTheDepartment(int department){
        double sum = 0;

        for (Employee employee: employees){
            if(employee != null && employee.getDepartment() == department){
                sum += employee.getSalary();
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
    public double averageSalary(int department){
        int countOfEmloyeesInTheDepartment = 0;

        double sumOfSalaryInTheDepartment = EmployeeBook.sumOfSalaryInTheDepartment(department);

        for (Employee employee: employees) {
            if(employee != null && employee.getDepartment() == department){
                countOfEmloyeesInTheDepartment += 1;
            }
        }
        return sumOfSalaryInTheDepartment / countOfEmloyeesInTheDepartment;
    }
}
```

Comment: Может есть другой вариант решения, без использования метода. Буду благодарен за каждый ответ.

Comment: Какой метод в каком методе? В чём конкретная проблема с этим кодом?

Comment: использовать метод sumOfSalaryInTheDepartment в методе averageSalary. 

проблема в строке double sumOfSalaryInTheDepartment = EmployeeBook.sumOfSalaryInTheDepartment(department);

не могу обратиться через EmloyeeBook, т.к метод non-static и не понимаю как создать обьект для использования метода

Comment: Этот метод использует массив employees для работы. Вы уверены, что вам нужно создать именно новый объект с новым employees, а не использовать какой-то уже существующий?

Comment: Вы всегда можете править свои посты: для этого достаточно воспользоваться 
ссылкой [edit] под текстом вашего поста. Важную информацию лучше включать
непосредственно в исходное сообщение, несмотря на то, что ответ уже дан: другим людям с этой же проблемой будет проще найти этот вопрос и ответ к нему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В нестатическом методе `averageSalary` НЕ нужно вызывать метод `sumOfSalaryInTheDepartment` как *статический*, используя имя класса.  Также НЕ нужно создавать никакой дополнительный объект, так как средняя зарплата вычисляется для *данного* экземпляра класса `EmployeeBook`.

Достаточно использовать ключевое слово `this` для указания ссылки на текущий экземпляр класса, у которого будет вычисляться суммарная зарплата, но в данном случае его можно опустить.

Также следует учесть, что количество служащих может оказаться равным 0 (при указании неверного отдела), тогда средняя зарплата не будет существовать вообще (возникнет деление на 0).  В таких случаях лучше возвращать `null` (в старом стиле) или же `OptionalDouble/Optional<Double>` с пустым значением.

```java
public Double averageSalary(int department) {
    int employeeCount = 0;
    for (Employee employee : employees) {
        if (employee != null && employee.getDepartment() == department) {
            employeeCount++;
        }
    }
 
    return employeeCount > 0 ? this.sumOfSalaryInTheDepartment(department) / employeeCount : null;
}
```

---

> *Может есть другой вариант решения, без использования метода.*

Конечно есть.  При указанном повторном использовании метода `sumOfSalaryInTheDepartment` получается лишняя итерация по массиву служащих, поэтому имеет смысл вычислять среднюю зарплату независимо (без вызова этого метода), то есть будет один проход по массиву.
Также лучше использовать известный параметр `countOfElements` в стандартном цикле `for`, чтобы избежать лишних проверок на `null`.

```java
public Double averageSalary(int department) {
    int employeeCount = 0;
    double deptSalary = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < countOfElements; i++) {
        Employee employee = employees[i];
        if (employee.getDepartment() == department) {
            deptSalary += employee.getSalary();
            employeeCount++;
        }
    }
 
    return employeeCount > 0 ? deptSalary / employeeCount : null;
}
```

---

*Для справки*: Вариант реализации с использованием Stream API, в частности [`Stream::filter`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-), [`Stream::mapToDouble`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-), [`DoubleStream::average`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#average--), возвращающим `OptionalDouble`:

```java
public OptionalDouble averageSalary(int department) {
    return Arrays.stream(employees) // Stream<Employee>
        .limit(countOfElements)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .filter(employee -> employee.getDepartment() == department)
        .mapToDouble(Employee::getSalary) // DoubleStream
        .average();
}
```